# HTML child css getting parent css

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML component that has it's opacity dynamically set with VUE. When the parent element (div) has the class opacity-50, the child element opacity is turned into 50%, even having the opacity-100 class with !important modifier.

How can i force the child to have 100% opacity while his parent has 50%?

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="opacity-50">
 <i class="fa-solid fa-plus opacity-100"></i>
 ...A lot more html that needs to be with 50% opacity...
</div>

<style>
.opacity-50{
   opacity: .5;
}
.opacity-50{
   opacity: 1 !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: you have a type as you have defined `.opacity-50` two times, did you intend to define `.opacity-100` instead?

Comment: opacity-100 class doesn't exist. I think you have a typo in your css because you have two same name classes.

Comment: You can't. The child is dependent on the parent. If the container opacity is 50%, then everything inside it will appear 50% as well.

Comment: You need to separate the 2 elements which you want the opacity to have different value. I agree with Sean as well.